# How to find a basis and dimension of subspace S?

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces

Let $S$ be a set of all square matrices $A$ with the size of $n \times n$, so that $A + A^T = diag\{a_1, ..., a_N\}$. Show that $S$ is a vector subspace of all square matrices $n \times n$ and find its basis and dimension.

I know how to prove that $S$ is a vector subspace. What is causing me problems is that I don't know how to work with sets of matrices to find the basis.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using this idea ?  Keep a11 as 1, and the remaining elements 0. Let this be your first basis element. Then a12 is 1, and the remaining elements, 0. I think you know where I'm going with this

Comment: But if I do that, the matrices won't follow the condition $A + A^T = diag\{a_1, .., a_n\}$, or am I missing something?

Comment: I still think it works. I mean, if it doesn't, tell me how.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** If $A+A^T$ is diagonal, that means that $A$ must be the sum of a diagonal and skew-symmetric matrix. The only matrix that is both is the zero matrix, so $S$ is the direct sum of these two other subspaces. Can you find bases for them?